# ScrollView OnScrollChangedListener

Tags: android, scrollview

I need to know if my `ScrollView` is at the top, bottom, or in the middle.

```
public class DialogInfo extends AlertDialog implements Constant, OnScrollChangedListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_informationen);

        ((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_farbe)).setON ???
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for some thing like this..

```
vertScroll.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener2);
```

where,

```
OnTouchListener gestureListener2 = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gdv.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
```

and..

```
GestureDetector gdv = new GestureDetector(vert);

SimpleOnGestureListener vert = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        .....
    }
};
```

I hope it helps..